# Freeform - get option label & value on submissions page

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

On the form I'm building, I've got a question with radio buttons. And the answers have custom values. e.g.

Q: What is your favorite color?

- red (value: 10)
- blue (value: 20)
- yellow (value: 30)

On my submissions page, I have the following code

```
{% for field in submission.fieldMetadata %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <b>{{ field.label }}/b>:
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        {% set fieldValue = attribute(submission, field.handle).value %}
        {% if fieldValue is iterable %}
        <ul>
            {% for value in FieldValue %}
            <li>{{ value }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% else %}
        {{ fieldValue }}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And this returns:

*What is your favorite color: 10*

I'm using the values to do some funny math - so it's necessary (but unimportant to the issue at hand).

How to do I get the value "red" to show, instead of the 10?

attribute(submission, field.handle).value - shows the selected option's value (10)

attribute(submission, field.handle).label - shows the question (What is your favorite Color?)

attribute(submission, field.handle).handle - shows the question handle (whatIsYourFavoriteColor)

There should be another function to get the option's value, but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is correct, but it turns out there was an actual bug in the code if you had a number as the option value.

This affects Freeform 1.5.1 and earlier. The next version (1.5.2) of Freeform will include a fix for this. If anyone needs a patched copy of Freeform before 1.5.2 is available, just contact us via our [support form](https://solspace.com/craft/create-ticket/freeform). :)